# Como deixar caixinhas uma ao lado da outra com CSS sem inline-block

Tags: css, css3

estou em um dilema. Tô querendo que 8 caixinhas fiquem uma ao lado da outra com CSS sem utilizar o display: inline-block pois eu consegui com essa propriedade mas ela não é aceita no pdf que é utilizado no meu trabalho.

Vou deixar uma foto de como tem que ficar. Agradeço muito se puderem me ajudar!!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a lib, pergunto porque as vezes dá para fazer com SVG ou Canvas mas sem saber qual a lib não da para afirmar se é possível.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, creio que um `display: flex`

```css
div.allBox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

div.box{
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="allBox">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se a lib do PDF não suporta `inline-block` acho meio difícil suportar `flex`... Acho que essa resposta foi um tiro no escuro. xD

Comment: Não tenho muito conhecimento sobre os "suportes", só respondi porque eu conheço o flex que faz a mesma coisa. Peço desculpas se foi "tiro no escuro", realmente eu não entendo sobre as compatibilidades

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar, você não fez nada errado. :) Acho que a resposta é válida, mas também _acho_ muito provável que o `flex` não irá ser suportado (já que o `inline-block` não é). No entanto, se quiser, deixe a resposta e vamos ver se ajuda o autor da pergunta.

Comment: É, eu também não sei se vai ser suportado mas eu vou testar com certeza e digo a vocês!

Comment: Realmente não foi compatível gente :(